# What kinds of initial value problems can have superposition of zero state response and zero input response?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering what kinds of initial value problems can have superposition of  [zero state response and zero input response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_state_response)?

[An example of initial value problem that has the superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_state_response#Zero_state_response_and_zero_input_response_in_integrator_and_differentiator_circuits) is 
$$
y'(t) = f(t), \quad y(0) = c.
$$
But are there other initial value problems that also have such superposition?

Also an initial value problem doesn't necessarily seem to have the superposition in general. 
[An initial value problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) is defined as (which is not necessarily first order):

> An initial value problem is a differential equation $$
>      y'(t) = f(t, y(t)) \, $$ with $$f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $$ where $\Omega \,$ is an open
>   set, together with a point in the domain of $ƒ$ $$
>      (t_0, y_0) \in \Omega, $$ called the initial condition.
>
> A solution to an initial value problem is a function $y$ that is a
>   solution to the differential equation and satisfies $$
>      y(t_0) = y_0. \, $$
>   **This statement subsumes problems of higher order**, by interpreting $y$ as a vector. For derivatives of second or higher order, new
>   variables (elements of the vector $y$) are introduced.

I think we also need to specify what an "input" is for an initial value problem.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your notation confusing. Therefore, I will denote the state by $x$, the input by $u$, and the vector field by $f$, which is the standard notation in control theory.

The [superposition principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) holds for all linear dynamical systems of the form

$$\dot{x} (t) = A (t) x(t) + B (t) u (t), \quad{} x(0) = x_0$$

where $x_0$ is the initial condition, $x : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the state trajectory, $u : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is the control input, and $A : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ are matrix-valued functions. This is a system of the form $\dot{x} (t) = f(t,x(t),u(t))$, where the time-varying vector field

$$f : [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$$

is defined by $f (t,x,u) = A (t) x + B(t) u$. Take a look at chapter 5 of [Hespanha's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=tvd4ILdJUQoC). Are there any other vector fields $f$ for which the [superposition principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) holds? I don't know.